# Why isn't pyinstaller making a Tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, discord, pyinstaller, python-3.9

It's important to know that I am using pyinstaller to package python.
tkinter works perfectly fine when I package it with only:

```py
import tkinter
root=tkinter.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

but when I add some more of my code it shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exec", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: Module use of python39.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

These are all my imports:

```py
import discord
import subprocess
from os import getcwd
import os
import pyautogui
from threading import *
import sys
```

I tried using only a tkinter window with no extra code and that worked!
But when I add the rest of my code it shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "exec", line 1, in \<module\>
import tkinter
File "C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib\\tkinter\__init_\_.py", line 36, in \<module\>
import \_tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: Module use of python39.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

Comment: The Module is compatible with older version of Python than you are using. You could try updating tkinter and other modules that have been imported if it's outdated using `pip install module_name --upgrade`

Comment: When PyInstaller is used to generate the executable, the Python embedded inside the executable should be used, but the error tells that the system installed Python is used instead.  Did you use something like `os.system("python ...")` (or `subprocess` module) inside your script?

Comment: Yes, I am using the subprocess module. Is that a problem? if it is how can I fix it because most of my code is based on the module

Comment: @acw1668 please answer I need this urgently

Comment: Use `sys.executable` instead of `"python"` in `subprocess` function, for example `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, ...])`.